# How do I make a live updated feed in my window using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to get a separate part of the window to output the text based on what happens e.g. 4 emails sent would look like : Sending...
                  Success:Email sent!
                  Success:Email sent!
                  Success:Email sent!
                  Success:Email sent!
                  All 4 emails have successfully been sent!

```
import smtplib
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Inbox Flooder")
root.geometry("720x520+0+0")
root.configure(background="black")

def click():
    global YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS , YOUR_PASSWORD , AMNT_REPEAT , TARGET_EMAIL , subject , msg
    YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS=YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS.get()
    YOUR_PASSWORD=YOUR_PASSWORD.get()
    TARGET_EMAIL=TARGET_EMAIL.get()
    subject=subject.get()
    msg=msg.get()
    AMNT_REPEAT=AMNT_REPEAT.get()
    print("Starting...")    

while int(AMNT_REPEAT) > 0 :
    send_email(subject, msg)
    AMNT_REPEAT = int(AMNT_REPEAT) - 1

if failed > 0 and sent > 0 :
    print(sent,"email(s) have been sucessfully sent and",failed ,"emails have failed to send.")

if failed > 0 and sent == 0 :
    print("All",failed ,"emails have failed to send.")

if failed == 0 and sent > 0 :
    print("All",sent ,"emails have sucessfully been sent!")


def send_email(subject, msg):
    global sent , failed
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS, YOUR_PASSWORD)
        message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject, msg)
        server.sendmail(TARGET_EMAIL, TARGET_EMAIL, message)
        server.quit()
        print("Sucess: Email sent!")
        sent = sent + 1

    except:
        print("Error: Email failed to send.")
        failed = failed + 1

def close_window():
    try:
        root.destroy()
        exit()

    except:
        print("Tab Closed")
```

Comment: Have you searched this site for an answer?  There are many very similar questions about updating the UI in a loop, or performing checks periodically.

Comment: why dont you use a tk.Label and configure it instead of the print statement?

Comment: or do a text and insert to keep track.

Comment: @BryanOakleyI tried looking but I couldn't find any

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple program that loops while the window is open adding "Success: Email sent!". This is nothing more than a demonstration of *how* to add content to a basic tkinter GUI.

However, you will need to use threads as your sending should be performed in the background while the window is open, which will require some proper research and I am not going to explain the process here (another SO thread should be easy enough to find).

```
import tkinter as tk

def send_success():
    # Allow us to insert into the widget
    logt.config(state="normal")
    # Insert into the widget (adding a newline at the end)
    logt.insert("end", "Success: Email sent!\n")
    # Disable user changes again
    logt.config(state="disabled")
    # Scroll to bottom of widget (to show new text)
    logt.see("end")
    # Schedule a call to ourselves after 1 second
    root.after(1000, send_success)

# Create the main tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create our text widget (normally a multi-line text
# entry widget, but this will be our log widget)
logt = tk.Text(root)
# Add the widget to the window
# (and set it to increase in size with the window)
logt.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
# Stop people changing the content
logt.config(state="disabled")

# Create a vertical scrollbar
sc = tk.Scrollbar(root)
# Add the widget to the window
sc.pack(side="right", fill="y")
# Move the text widget when scrollbar moved
sc.config(command=logt.yview)
# Change scrollbar length when new content added
logt.config(yscrollcommand=sc.set)

# Schedule our method to run once the mainloop is running
root.after(0, send_success)

# Run the mainloop
# This handles window actions (moving, resizing, etc.)
root.mainloop()
```